# dialog not working as properly after JqueryUI1.9.2 upgrade

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Initialization used to work properly before upgrade, but now this statement alters my dialog div width and dialog opens with improper width. 
(Jquery version I am using is 1.10.2 with JqueryUI 1.9.2 )

```
function ShowAdvSearch() {
var titleText = 'Search';
var divAdvSearch = $(GetDivAdvSearch());

SetWidthHeightOfSearchDiv();  // sets the hight and width of grid to 670x480

divAdvSearch.css('overflow-x', 'auto');
divAdvSearch.css('overflow-y', 'auto');
divAdvSearch.dialog({ autoOpen: false });  // Problem is here


divAdvSearch.dialog("option", { modal: true, title: titleText, maxWidth: 1247, maxHeight: 1000,
    resizeStop: function(event, ui) {
        SetWidthHeightOfSearchDiv();
    },
    dragStop: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
```

After the code passes the initialization (**divAdvSearch.dialog({ autoOpen: false });** ) the width of the DIV becomes 50px for some reason. What changed after upgrade, I read the documentation and upgrade guide but could not find anything.

Update : I debugged through the ui library and found out that the following statement is causing problem :

**$.data( this, fullName, new object( options, this ) );**

when it saves the data it resets the width of the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to update the jqueryUi CSS accordingly and initialize the dialog once again in the code (which is weird but it works).